# Find even sum from a given set

Tags: combinatorics

For a set that contains $=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$

How many times minimally do I have to randomly pick a number from the set to ensure the sum is even?

Comment: any thought about the question?

Comment: Hint: for a bad scenario, you must first draw an odd number and thereafter draw even numbers.

Comment: Is there any general formula to use?

Comment: Please show some efforts.  If you can solve the problem in this case, I think you will see how to do it in general.

Comment: Do refer to my working below,i am not sure if it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remember: $$even+even=even$$
$$odd+odd=even$$
$$odd+even=odd$$

If you want to ensure the sum is even, you have to find the maximum number of picks.
$$odd+even+even+even+even=odd$$ is the maximum number of picks to get odd.

So minimum of picks to ensure you have an even sum is **six**.

Comment: @user10456099 so?

Comment: even+odd+odd/even = even OR
odd+even+odd/even   = even

Comment: So,3 maximum picks if same number cannot be pick again?

Comment: Yes if you cannot have even-even or odd-odd after each other, than the it must be 3, but that was not the question right?

Comment: No,My question was if i randomly picked number 2,i can no longer able to pick number 2 again.I may randomly picked any number other than 2 in the set.

Comment: So,the solution to question is still 3?

Comment: If you pick first number 2, you can add any other number that is odd (so 1,3,5,7,9), than you can pick any other even number (so 4,6,8), than again you have to pick an even number (4,6,8, minus the one already picked) and than there's is only one even number left (4,6,8, minus the two already picked). And than the only numbers left are odd, so the sixth pick will give you an even sum.